# I'm making a code for a basic number guessing game. There seems to be error with my column on line 7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from random import randint
random_number = randint(1, 10)  
while guess_left > 0:  
    print "you need to guess the number"  
    print "you have d% guess left" % guess_left  
    answer = raw_input("What is your guess between 1 and 10?"  
    if 0 <= answer <= 10: ### HERE! 
        if answer == random_number:  
            print "You win!"  
            break  
        else:  
            print "Please try again"  
            guesses_left -= 1  
    else:  
        print "choose a valid answer"  
else:  
    print "You lost the number was %d" % random_number  
guesses_left = 3
```

When I tried it on idle it gave me an error with that specific column but from what I know which is not a lot there need to be a ":" at the end of each if statement.

Comment: Is there a missing `)` on the end of the `"What is your guess. . ."` line? Will that break it?

Comment: **Which** error do you get? Have you read it? What does it say?

Comment: oups yes I missed that too thanks a lot

Comment: you must set `guesses_left` before `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using raw_input as a number, but it is a string, convert it to an int:

```
if 0 <= int(answer) <= 10: ### HERE!
```

You also did not initialize guess_left, and you have a variable guesses_left which is confusing.

```
# place at top after the import
guess_left = 3
```

You are also missing a closing ) on your raw_input line.

```
answer = raw_input("What is your guess between 1 and 10?")
```

You are also formatting wrong:

```
print "you have %d guess left" % guess_left
```